# Google App Script don't known native Javascript anymore?? let, includes(), Object.Values()

Tags: google-apps-script

my code was running well for months since today.
Now Google App Script is telling that

- 'let',
- 'includes()',
- 'Object.Values()'
  and others javascript native functions are ERROR or unknown!!!
  somme body have the same problem ?

Comment: `Object.Values()` might be `Object.values()` [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) I think that `let`, `includes()` and `Object.values()` can be used with Google Apps Script, when V8 runtime is enabled at the script editor. How about this?

Comment: Have you enabled v8

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) you have to enable the V8 runtime enviroment:

---

Enabling the V8 runtime
If a script is using the Rhino runtime, you can switch it to V8 by doing the following:

1. Open the script in the Apps Script editor.
2. Select the Run > Enable new Apps Script runtime powered by V8.
3. Save your script.

Alternatively you can select the script runtime directly by editing the script manifest file:

1. Open the script in the Apps Script editor.
2. Select View > Show project manifest.
3. In the resulting appsscript.json manifest file, set the
   runtimeVersion field to the value V8.
4. Save your script.