# Google Scripts let returns "missing ; before statement", the same code ok when using var

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The code below **works in one sheet, but returns error in another**: "Missing ; before statement".
Occurs on the line
let e = events[i];

So basically, code is ok as it works in one sheet. But in another sheet it works only if using
var e = events[i];

It works anyway, but of course, would be nice to know why? Most probably some sheet setting or something I'm missing here?

```
function getHolidays() {
  var startTime = new Date(2020,1-1,1);
  var endTime = new Date(2020,12-1,31);
  var calendarChoice = 'sl.slovenian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com';
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarChoice);
  var events = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
  {
    let e = events[i];
    data.push([e.getStartTime(), e.getTitle(), e.getDescription(), e.getAllTagKeys().join(',')]);    
  }
  
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Google Calendar + Script');
  s.getRange(2, 7, data.length, 4).setValues(data)
}
```

Comment: the only line with missing `;` is `s.getRange(2, 7, data.length, 4).setValues(data)` ... add one there - if that fixes the problem, then you know that somehow the line you think the error is on is wrong

Comment: Where is this code executed? Or who is telling you the error? The IDE? Or when you run the script?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using this exact code? This code is perfectly fine for Apps Script, it shouldn't throw this error. How are you executing this?

Comment: The answer is below, the issue was in the runtime engine version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that the script project given the error is set to use the old runtime (Rhino) instead of the new runtime (Chrome V8) as th old runtime doesn't support `let`.

Possible solution: Enable the new runtime.

Related

- [Declaring variables on Google sheet script editor using let](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48654622/1595451)
- [Google App Script don't known native Javascript anymore?? let, includes(), Object.Values()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63110458/1595451)

Comment: Indeed, that's it. Yet the issue remains as the some parts of code do not work in V8 - that's why I've left it in previous version. 
But thanks anyway, I really wanted to know. :)